# Sitecore: base template item of a page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8.1

I have a page Item in Sitecore, and I know it is derived from a certain base template. I have that base template ID, but I want to get the instance of this base template that is part of my page. I want it as an item, so for example I can get the ID of the template internal of the page.

To be more clear:

- Page called A1 of template A
- Template A has as base template the template B
- B is part of page A1 as an instance called B1 (field values specific for the page A1)

How can I get B1 as stand alone Item/ID? 
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you mean? why would you want to get the instance of an inheriting template? the item would have all fields you've inherited available anyway via item.fields[templateBFieldId].Value

You could do something like check if the current item inherits from that template.. so something like:

```
public static bool InheritsFrom(this Item item, ID templateId)
    {
        return item.Template.DoesTemplateInheritFrom(templateId);
    }

    public static bool DoesTemplateInheritFrom(this TemplateItem template, ID templateId)
    {
        if (template == null || templateId.IsNull)
            return false;
        if (!(template.ID == templateId))
            return template.DoesTemplateInheritFrom(TemplateManager.GetTemplate(templateId, template.Database));
        return true;
    }

private static bool DoesTemplateInheritFrom(this TemplateItem template, Template baseTemplate)
        {
            if (baseTemplate == null)
                return false;

            return TemplateManager.GetTemplate(template.ID, template.Database).DescendsFromOrEquals(baseTemplate.ID);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @nologo for you reply. This code is usefull, i have a method "IsDerived" to do this. I would have the instance ID of the template because I want to add an EditFrame button on it. I want to add this and not on the item it belongs to avoid synonyms fields on this and edit it from Experience Editor

Answer (score 0):

I was getting confused about the contents of the''yml. There is no instance of the base template within the page item